# renderscript.support.mode=true doesn't seem to have affect

Tags: android, renderscript

I specified in my project.properties

```
renderscript.target=18 
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

and imported the V8-Library into the project.
When I clean my project, all my generated RS-Classes still import "android.renderscript.*";

However, I need android.support.v8.renderscript, otherwise the types are not compatible. How do I force the compiler to create classes with the support-package import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing the whole "eclipse" folder from the one that comes with the ADT-Bundle, it seems to work now. All the scripts include the support.v8 now. I'm not sure what was wrong, but it seems like the Eclipse-Version may was to old.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to upgrade the eclipse to Kepler.

1) Help > Check for Updates > Update All ADT
2) Run Android SDK Manager > Update Android SDK Build-tools to 19.0.3
3) In your project.properties file, add the below lines:

```
renderscript.target=19   
renderscript.support.mode=true   
sdk.buildtools=19.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow all the steps on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis. Check to be sure that you have:
1) Android SDK Tools revision 22.2 or higher
2) Android SDK Build-tools revision 18.1.0 or higher

Without those, the SDK build rules don't know anything at all about the support library (and hence will always generate code that targets android.renderscript.* instead).

Comment: SDK Tools Rev 22.3, SDK BUild-Tools 19 - Followed all the steps... (There are not many details, though). May a problem with the new releases?

Comment: Did you also set "sdk.buildtools=18.1.0" or 19.0.0?

Comment: Tried both with and without - using Eclipse

Comment: Any ideas? Is there any flag I could set directly on the executable compiler-file?